c++ and std::float64_t how to use it
It seems that the new standard c++ defined the types float32_t float64_t etc.
I cannot compile any code that uses it.
#include <stdfloat>

int main() {
  std::float64_t f = 0;
}

What do I have to do to use them ?
For compiling I use -std=c++23 and both g++ or clang++

g++ -std=gnu23 testfloat.cpp cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-std=gnu23’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ testfloat.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: testfloat.cpp:4:8: error: ‘float64_t’ is not a member of ‘std’ 4 | std::float64_t f = 0;


I cannot compile any code that uses it. This should be followed by the verbatim error message so other users can search this question and an answer.

Any attempt to RTM and look at the example? The answer starts from the first sentence of the manual. These types are optional and available if appropriate macros are defined.

Works here.  You failed to mention the version of clang and g++ you are using.

I use -std=c++23 and both g++ or clang++ Are you sure? Can you show the exact build command and exact errors? I mean if you are using VSCode and set this in c_cpp_properties.json that file is for Intellisense only and not building.

gcc version 14.2.0 (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2~24.04)

clang version 20.0.0git (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git fcb7b390ccd5b4cfc71f13b5e16a846f3f400c10)

May be those versions should be compiled with some flags supporting that ?

g++  -std=gnu23 testfloat.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-std=gnu23’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
testfloat.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testfloat.cpp:4:8: error: ‘float64_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
4 |   std::float64_t f = 0;

clang++  -std=c++23 testfloat.cpp

What's the point?  float and double have well-defined meanings.  There is no ambiguity.  That can't be said of int and long.

@TimRoberts -- float and double are pretty much like int and long in the standard. They are often implemented as IEEE binary32 and binary64, respectively, but that is not required.

Please [edit] the question and repost the error in a code block, not a quotation, so the error message is kept pre-formatted.

-std=gnu23 is C23 with GNU extensions. You wanted -std=gnu++23 or -std=c++23

As already mentioned in the comments, -std=gnu23 or -std=c23 stands for the C standard C23 (prefix gnu means gnu extensions, whereas the c prefix specifies ISO standard). To determine the C++23 language standard, the command line option has to be either -std=c++23 (iso) or -std=gnu++23 (gnu extensions).
See: GCC - Options Controlling C Dialect - std
And if you're going to use new magic, it's best to do it in a sandbox, because it takes a while for the compiler suites to implement the standard, keyword here: feature test macros, e.g.
#if __STDCPP_FLOAT64_T__ != 1
    #error "64-bit float type required"
#endif

as can be seen in the example of this page: Fixed width floating-point types (since C++23)
Hint: Compiler support for C++23
